Filter stored procedure list in Visual Studio Code
Sometimes I use Visual Studio Code with SQL extensions. I didn't find a way to filter DB objects.
For example how can I filter list of stored procedures?

Not need to be detail functionality of SSMS, basic name filter is enough.

I searched the site and web.
Object filter feature request for the SQL Server Extension on VSCode #1009

This sounds more like a feature request for the addon that anything. Azure Data Studio (ADS) does have this feature, which is an (in house) fork of VSCode.

@Thom A Thanks. Yes Azure Data Studio has filter feature but VS Code seems more developer centric. You can organise Sql query files into folders for re use. SSMS Project structure is weak. SSMS is a good app but needs to be devloped.

ADS has Database Projects.

I have hundreds of Sql query files. Some of them are for reporting, daily usage etc. I dont need a project that after building creates a db with db objects. I need to well organize my query, daily working files.

And ADS supports that. If you want object filtering in the object explorer, and specifically want to use VSCode, then raise a feature request for the extension on VSCode; it might be added in the (near) future.

Thanks a lot. I m looking for those properties. Clasify the wuery files and run when needed. I will raise a feature request for the VSCode Sql extension.

Object filter feature request link
